# The right way of using index.html

Tags: seo, google-search, html, directory-index

*I have quite a lot of issues I'd like to hear your opinion on, so I hope I'll manage to explain it well enough. I should also note that I'm beginner equipped only with the knowledge of HTML and CSS so although I'm almost sure that there is a simple solution using powerful PHP, **it won't help me**.*

Let's say that I have my personal blog on the address `example.com/blog.html` and there are links to several sub-blogs `example.com/blog/math.html`, `example.com/blog/coding.html` etc. So my root folder contains `blog.html` and `blog` folder, the `blog` folder itself contains files `math.html` and `coding.html`.

First of all, I learned (from [Google Webmasters Tools](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066&topic=2371375&ctx=topic)) that for SEO and aesthetical purposes it's good to unify `example.com.com` and `example.com/index.html` by adding `_rel="canonical"_` attribute into the source of the `index.html`. Using a couple of other tricks (like linking to `../` and `./`) I got rid of the ugly `index.html` appearing in my web addresses.

And now I wonder if this trick can be used not only for the root folder but for **any** folder? I mean, I would move my `blog.html` into the `blog` folder, rename it into the `index.html` and add `rel="canonical"` to unify `example.com/blog/index.html` with `example.com/blog/`.
This trick would change the address of my blog from `example.com/blog.html` into `example.com/blog/`.

Not finished! I'm also experiencing problems with the google robot indexing my folders. So when I type `site:example.com/` into the google search, the link to my folder `example.com/blog/` with raw files, icons etc. appears among the other results. I guess there are also other ways how to fix it, but IMHO the change mentioned above would do the trick too - the *index.html* in the blog folder would preserve the user from viewing the actual raw content of that folder, there would appear only the right link `example.com/blog/` in the google search and (I hope that) `_rel="canonical"_` would make the second, unwanted link `example.com/blog/index.html` not to appear in the search results.

So my questions are:

1. Is it a good practice to have the `index.html` file in every subfolder or is it intended to be only in the root folder?
2. Are there any disadvantages or problems that may occur when using the second, "*index in every folder*" method?
3. Which one of the two ways of structuring the website described above would **you** prefer?

Comment: For my clarification, do search engines see http://www.site.com/blog/ and http://www.site.com/blog/index.html as being 2 distinct files? If links with both URLs are being used, is there a chance you are splitting link juice/page authority between 2 locations?

Comment: As far as I know, search engines (at least Google) DO see them as two distinct files. Because they actually can be distinct - the two links can differ only in one single slash. (Read more [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.cz/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html).) And yes, if you're using two different links to one page, the whole rank of the page is split between those two links and your page is effectively loosing the half of its rank. That's why I suggest the mentioned link canonicalization to prevent those leaks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason we use `index.html` or `home.html` or derivitives thereof, is because the webserver software *itself* actually looks for that and serves it. For example:

This is INVALID: (www-directory)

```
/var/www/
|_blog.html
|_blog/
  |_math.html
  |_page2.html
  |_page3.html
  |_(...)
```

This will in fact get served as a page listing the folders and files. (Not what you want). You can try this structure, but also make an index.html file next to blog.html. Notice how it will not serve blog.html unless you specify `http://www.site.com/blog.html`) This is why `http://www.google.com/` shows the page without you having to specify `http://www.google.com/index.html`

This is VALID:

```
/var/www/
|_index.html (renamed blog.html to index.html)
|_blog/
  |_math.html
  |_page2.html
  |_page3.html
  |_(...)
```

This will serve your `blog.html` file AS THE HOMEPAGE. (Not list all the folders/files in that directory)

The webserver software has (in the config) a specialized list of file names that will be served as the homepage or the main page of a folder. (In my experience, `index.html` takes precedence over index.php, so if you have `index.html` and `index.php` in a folder, the index.html is what the public will see) Of course that can all be changed, and you can even set `blog.html` to be recognized as an "index".

Addressing your comment:

> "This trick would change the address of my blog from
>   www.xxx.com/blog.html into www.xxx.com/blog/."

This would be done by moving `blog.html` entirely into `/blog/` and renaming it to index.html.

Your new structure would be:

```
/var/www/
|_blog/
  |_index.html (renamed from blog.html)
  |_math.html
  |_page2.html
  |_page3.html
  |_(...)
```

This should correctly serve `http://www.site.com/blog/` to show the contents of your blog.html which we renamed to `index.html` so the software could set it as the index of your directory `/blog/`

You're also free now to put and `index.html` file into the root of your site `http://www.site.com/(index.html)` to have links to `/blog/` and whatever else you wish.

Specifically answering your questions in short statements:

1. **Is it a good practice to have the index.html file in every subfolder or is it intended to be only in the root folder?**

   Yes, because it prevents people from seeing what files are in your directories. You can prevent this with a `.htaccess` file containing `Options -Indexes`
2. **Are there any disadvantages or problems that may occur when using the second, "index in every folder" method?**

   None that I can think of.
3. **Which one of the two ways of structuring the website described above would you prefer?**

   I usually have an `index.html` or `index.php` file in the root, subfolders based on category (such as `forum` or `news` or `login` etc.) and then some sort of index inside each of those.

Comment: Thank you for such comprehensive answer! That public access to my folders and the fact that they are indexed by google, makes me quite angry so now when I know that there's no problem with the "index in every folder" trick, I will change my website this way. I just hope that the rel="canonical" trick will work and all those indexes won't appear in the google search... :D

Answer (score 6):

The technical term for index.html is Directory Index for Apache and Default Document for IIS.  The other Apache directive of interest is the [Options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options) directive.  As indicated in the documentation, when `Options Indexes` is set:

> If a URL which maps to a directory is requested, and there is no DirectoryIndex (e.g., index.html) in that directory, then mod_autoindex will return a formatted listing of the directory.

When I setup a website that is not using a content management system, my preferred setup is to have one content page per directory. That page is the directory index (default document) for the directory.  All links on the site only link to the directory and end with a trailing slash (e.g., `http://example.com/blog/` instead of `http://example.com/blog/index.html` or `./blog/` instead of `./blog/index.html`).  The trailing slash is important to avoid what is commonly referred to as a [courtesy redirect](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298408).  (If the trailing slash is omitted, everything still resolves correctly, but the number of HTTP requests and thus bandwidth increase.)

My primary motivation for the above methodology is twofold.  First, it facilitates switching the technology used on the website.  For example, I can change a page from index.html to index.php without breaking any links or search engine listings.  Second, the file extension of a content page is "noise"; removing the file extension from the URL results in shorter and hopefully more readable URLs.

As for other file types:

- All CSS files reside in a css directory in the root of the website.
- All image files reside in an image directory or subdirectory thereof in the root of the website.
- All JavaScript files reside in a scripts directory in the root of the website.
- All flash and other movie files reside in a video directory or subdirectory thereof in the root of the website.

On an Apache server, I disable `Options Indexes` for the abovementioned directories.  On both Apache and IIS servers, I do not specify a directory index (default document) for the abovementioned directories.  Thus, a request for any of the directories results in an HTTP 403 error.

Comment: Due to the two link limit restriction, I could not include links to [Directory Index](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) and [Default Document](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument) in my answer, so here they are.